# How to return data from R notebook task to Python task in databricks

Tags: python, r, databricks

I have a simple function in an R notebook (notebook A) that aggregates some data. I want to call notebook A from another notebook (notebook B) and interogate the aggregated data from notebook A in notebook B.

So far I can run notebook A from notebook B no problem, but cannot see any returned data, variables or functions.

Code in notebook A:

```
function_to_aggregate_data = function(x,y){
 ...some code...
 }
aggregated_data = function_to_aggregate_data(x,y)
```

Code in notebook B:

```
%python
dbutils.notebook.run("path/to/notebook_A", 60)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `dbutils.notebook.run`, that notebook is executed as a separate job, so no variables, etc. are available for the caller notebook, or in the called notebook.  You can return some data from the notebook using `dbutils.notebook.exit`, but it's limited to 1024 bytes (as I remember).  But you can return data by registering temp view, and then accessing data in this temp view - here is an example of doing that (although using Python for both).

[Notebook B](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-nutter-repos-demo/blob/master/Code1.py#L8):

```py
def generate_data1(n=1000, name='my_cool_data'):
  df = spark.range(0, n)
  df.createOrReplaceTempView(name)
```

Notebook A:

```py
dbutils.notebook.run('./Code1', default_timeout)
df = spark.sql("select * from my_cool_data")
assert(df.count() == 1000)
```

P.S. You can't directly share data between R & Python code, only by using temp views, etc.

Comment: Marked as answer - thanks very much for this!